# Block Shadows appearing in volumes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shadows, volumetrics, mantaflow

I have these strange shadows emerging from a smoke simulation. I circled them with the red. They don't seem to be correlated with any actual density of smoke in the simulation. Placing a plane above the volume shows that there are no other objects accidentally casting them. They appear at random per frame and cause a messy vibrating shadow.
I've been struggling with sourcing this issue and re-running the simulation did not solve the issue. They do decrease in size with higher resolution but there are more of them and they seem to disappear below a resolution of 200.[image: rendered image of shadow issues]
Turning off Adaptive resolution did not solve the issue. All shaders have been disabled and I only have a principled volume plugged in currently.

Comment: I also am having this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I increased the samples for Render Properties > Light Paths > Transparency (using Cycles) and the weird shadow blocks disappeared.